# webpack. scss. duplicate code after @extend

Tags: webpack, sass-loader

I'm trying to figure out how to build styles in a webpack and I'm having a problem. I would like css classes that using the same @extend to be grouped together to avoid duplication of code.

I have files:

**common.scss:**

```css
p {
    margin: 0 0 1em;
}

%common {
    display: flex;
}
```

**c1.scss:**

```css
@import "./common.scss";

.c1 {
    @extend %common;
}
```

**c2.scss:**

```css
@import "./common.scss";

.c2 {
  @extend %common;
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```css
...
   module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['babel-loader'],
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'js')
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader'
                        }
                    ]
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin("./css/style.css"),
        new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
            assetNameRegExp: /css\/style.css$/,
            cssProcessor: cssNano,
            cssProcessorOptions: {
                autoprefixer: { add: true },
                discardDuplicates: true,
                discardComments: {removeAll: true }
            }
        })
    ]
...
```

At the output, I received a minified file (I unminified it for show)

**style.css**

```css
.c1 {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 1em
}

.c2 {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex
}
```

Is it possible to make classes that use the same @extend (in this case %common) grouped? 
Like below:

```css
.c1, .c2 {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 1em
}
```

postcss-merge-rules - looks like what I need, but here http://cssnano.co/optimisations/ indicates that this option is enabled by default. I tried to include it myself, indicating mergeRules: true in cssProcessorOptions, but this did not work.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue with `sass-loader`, there is an alternative [`sass-loader-once`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader-once) that uses `node-sass-import-once` under the hood, just use it.

Checkout that thread: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/145#issuecomment-272800892

Comment: Sorry, it seems it does not work. I changed sass-loader to sass-loader-once like this:
`{
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader-once'
                        }
                    ]
                })
            }`
and received same result.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: if I understand correctly, [there](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/145#issuecomment-272800892) recommend using `optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin`, but I already use it.